# How to parse Date from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am using a grid view which is getting bind by json also on some conditions and a coloum of grid contains date , so while getting data from json, I need to parse the date. I am able to get date but not time part . Tried and searched too much . I am mentioning below two methods that I tried but not solves my problem.

```
{
       function ParseDate(jsonDate) {
       date = new Date(parseInt(String(jsonDate).substr(6)));
       day = date.getDate();
       month = date.getMonth() + 1;
       year = date.getFullYear();
       return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  }
}
```

This gives me only date but I need time, so I did one more method

```
{
    function ParseDate(jsonDate) {
        var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
        var formatted = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + "0" + date.getSeconds();
        return formatted;

    }
}
```

but this function returns

```
    //07/19/2013 11:38
```

instead of  `//7/19/2013 11:38:07 AM` which is desired result.Please help me solving this problem. Thank You very much. Also , I need to show Am or PM that is compulsory

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the parameter that is being passed in to the ParseDate method?

Comment: this is the parameter :  /Date(1374214080650)/

Comment: I am really very sorry , I have got the date and time but not AM or Pm with the date

Comment: How can I come to know abot AM or Pm from this

Comment: It's 'AM' if date.getHours() is less then 12 otherwise is 'PM'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function ParseDateToLocale(jsonDate) {
    var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
    var myDate = new Date(date);
    var formatted = myDate.toLocaleString();
    return formatted;
}
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/2ft3A/.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, this will help you,

```
function ParseDate(jsonDate) {
        var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
        var merd='';
        if(date.getHours()>=12)
        {
            merd='PM';
        }
        else
        {
            merd='AM';
        }

        var formatted = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + "0" + date.getSeconds()+ " " + merd;

        return formatted;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

dateObject.toLocaleTimeString(); 
(OR)
 date.getHours() will return 0-24hrs. Base on that value you can append AM or PM